# Not able to debug COM registered library

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, com

I have a .net dll. For some reasons I have registered it for COM. I tried a lot of options to debug the code of this dll but nothing has worked. Someone please suggest a way to debug the code of COM registered .net assembly.

Comment: You'll need to debug the client, either by starting it from the debugger or by attaching to the running process.  You'll need to have managed debugging enabled.  You'll need to have the .pdb file accessible to the debugger (in all cases where I've done this, the .pdb file is in the same folder as the COM component).

Comment: Thanks, Now I am able to debug my dll.

Comment: Great!  Since it worked for you, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to debug the client, either by starting it from the debugger or by attaching to the running process. You'll need to have managed debugging enabled. You'll need to have the .pdb file accessible to the debugger (in all cases where I've done this, the .pdb file is in the same folder as the COM component).